# JPA Counting members

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jpql

```
@Query("select count(s) from S s, TG tg where s.id = :id and tg member of s.tgs and :user member of tg.members")
@Query("select count(s) from S s, TG tg, FG fg where s.id = :id and tg member of s.tgs and :user member of fg.members and fg member of tg.members")
@Query("select count(s) from S s, TG tg, FG fg where s.id = :id and tg member of s.tgs and (:user member of tg.members or :user member of fg.members and fg member of tg.members)")
```

I have 3 queries in JPA. The goal is to count the number of S entities where user is a member. S entities are link with two kind of group TG (directly) and FG (can be member of TG). User can be member of TG or FG.

As you can see the third one is the addition of the two firsts.

The two firsts requests seems to work, but the third...:

1. When I have 0 user the 3 requests return 0 (expected)
2. When I add a user in a TG, the first return 1 (expected), the second 0 (expected) and the third 0 (**not expected**)
3. When I add the user in a FG that is in a TG the 3 requests return 1 (**not expected** I must have 2)
4. When the user is in the FG only, the first request return 0 (expected) and the two others return 1 (expected)

I can't understand!!! Why the third query is not returning the results of the first and second queries???

Edit: Entities (schemas are autogenerated by JPA)

```
    @Entity
public class S {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  public long id;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "s_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tg_id"))
  private List<TG> tgs = new ArrayList<>();

  (...)

}

@Entity
public class TG extends G {

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tgs", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<S> ss = new ArrayList<>();

  (...)

}


@Entity
public class FG extends G {

  @Column(nullable = false)
  public String uniqueName;

  (...)

}


@Entity(name = "groupe")
public abstract class G extends Subject {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "membres")
    private Set<Subject> membres = new HashSet<>();

    (...)

}


@Entity
public class U extends Subject {

  @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
  public String uniqueName;

  (...)

}


@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Subject {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  public long id;

  (...)

}
```

Comment: Don't have any idea what your schema is so I don't know how this question can be evaluated.

Comment: Sorry! I add entites classes. Schemas are autogenerated